# Issue with changing storage type in aerospike

Tags: aerospike

i’ve just added the new namespace in aerospike, but i’ve make a mistake, i choose storage engine memory but this is wrong, because the storage engine must be device ( in my case). is it safe to change the storage memory of existing namespace? or which way i can go to change that, without deleting namespace? P.S I have a pretty old version 3.7.4 Thank you!

Comment: Cross posted here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-change-storage-type-in-aerospike/4988

When cross posting, please update posts with a links to the other posting. See: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/cross-posting-to-from-other-sites-such-as-stack-overflow/4526

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to simply change your conf to specify the device for storage and restart aerospike on that node. You should wait for the migration to finish before doing the same on the next node. This is because there is only one copy of the data when you remove the old storage.

Comment: This is true assuming the cluster has at least 2 nodes and replication-factor for the namespace is at least 2. Otherwise the user will need to do a backup/restore.